# How to overcome error while compiling gtk programs in windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, gtk

i have installed gtk and mingw in windows and compile the program with the following command

```
    set VAR=-mms-bitfields -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/cairo -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/freetype2 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/libpng14  -LC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0-lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl

    gcc a.c %VAR%
```

and i have got the following error

```
C:\Users\kiran\Desktop\gtk>gcc a.c -mms-bitfields -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/inclu
de/gtk-2.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle
/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/cairo -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle
/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/Windows/
gtk+-bundle/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/
Windows/gtk+-bundle/include -IC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/include/freetype2 -IC:/Wind
ows/gtk+-bundle/include/libpng14  -LC:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -
lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0-lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgd
k_pixbuf-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lgli
b-2.0 -lintl
C:\Windows\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgio-2.0-lpangowin32-1.0
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Hmm, did you try putting a space between "-lgio-2.0-lpangowin32-1.0
" in your parameters? As in "-lgio-2.0[SPACE]-lpangowin32-1.0"

Comment: thats correct.but i have got the entire command by pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the spacing issue, should be `-lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0`, not `-lgio-2.0-lpangowin32-1.0`. If you still have a similar error, check the libs not found are available in the directories you passed to gcc with the `-L` option (ie. `C:/Windows/gtk+-bundle/lib`)

BTW, prefer the [syntax advised by GTK](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/gtk-compiling.html), it prevents copy/pasting issues:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0) hello.c -o hello
```

You may need to add `pkg-config` to your `PATH`, and maybe the directory where your .pc files are to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.